# Java Normalizer class not properly normalizing Korean syllables

Tags: java, unicode, normalize

I am trying to use Java's Normalizer class to combine `ㅇ,ㅞ,ㄴ` to `웬`. After normalizing the string, it would output `웨ㄴ`.

If I do `String x = "ㅇㅞᆹ"` and `Normalizer.normalize(x, Normalizer.Form.NFKC)` It works fine and outputs `웺`.

Also I would like to note that sometimes the same character has different numerical codes:

```
public void normalize() {
    char test[] = {'ㅄ'};
    System.out.println((int)'ㅄ');
    System.out.println((int)test[0]);
}
```

output:

```
4537
12612
```

What am I doing wrong? Why won't Java normalize the characters into a single syllable and why are the same characters producing different numerical values?

Comment: I can't reproduce your output. It prints the same number each time.

Comment: I guess that the character codes got modified when they were pasted into the code block above. But the character in question is defined twice in Unicode: once in the [Hangul Jamo block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangul_Jamo_(Unicode_block) ), and once in the [Hangul Compatibility Jamo block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangul_Compatibility_Jamo). So you did nothing wrong, you just used two different code points for the same character.